# Does this claim depend on topology?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

An *open rectangle* is a set $R\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ of the form $R=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2;\;a<x<b\text{ and }c<y<d\}$, where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$, $a<b$ and $c<d$.

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$. The *open ball of radius $\varepsilon>0$ centered at $a\in\mathbb{R}^2$* is the set $B(a;\varepsilon)=\{z\in\mathbb{R}^2;\|z-a\|<\varepsilon\}$.

If we define an *open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$* as a set $U\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ such that for all $x\in U$ there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B(x;\varepsilon)\subset U$, then **every open set $U\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is a countable union of open rectangles**.

Is it always true? In other words, let $(\mathbb{R}^2,\tau)$ be an arbitary topological space. Is every set $U\in\tau$ a countable union of open rectangles? Is it possible to characterize the topologies $\tau$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ for which it's true?

Comment: Note that since you consider arbitrary topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$, the original structure of $\mathbb{R}^2$ has no significance more. You are just considering arbitrary topological space of size continuum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the discrete topology, then $\{(x,y)\}$ is open but it is not the countable union of open rectangles.

On characterization of such topologies: you can show in quite a direct manner that if all open rectangles are open sets, then all open balls are open sets and the other way round. The intuition being that the $\max$-norm and the euclidean norm agree on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Reasoning in a more topological fashion: you show that every open rectangle contains an open ball around all of its points and that every open ball contains an open rectangle around all of its points, which shows that the topologies are equivalent.

Edit: I have exchanged all triangles for rectangles. Sorry, read something about triangles before... but worth mentioning: you can use all kinds of open polygons, where you have to take a bit care of how you define their openness in absence of a topology (ex ante).

Comment: Thanks. (I added one more question in the post)

Comment: @Pedro I have added something relating to the your question.